# SQL query to get output on the basis of 3 columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I have 3 columns `liqn_days`, `liq_months` and `liqn_years`.

- If `liqn_days` has value and others are 0, then print Monthly
- If `liq_months` is 3 and others are 0, then get output as quarterly
- If `liq_months` is 6 and other columns are 0, then output will be half yearly
- If `liqn_years` has a value and others are 0, then output will be  yearly

Sample data:

```
liqn_days  liq_months  liqn_years 
---------------------------------    
 0          0             1
12          0             0
 0          3             0
```

- Output for 1st row - Yearly
- Output for 2st row  - Monthly
- Output for 3rd row - quarterly

Please assist me in this

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Use a `case` _expression_.

Comment: I think your expected output for the 2nd and 3rd rows are backwards, and need to be swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` expression :

```
select t.*, (case when liqn_days > 0 and liq_months = 0 and liqn_yearsand = 0
                  then 'Monthly'
                  when liq_months = 3 and liqn_days = 0 and liqn_yearsand = 0
                  then 'quarterly'
                  when liq_months =  6 and liqn_days = 0 and liqn_yearsand = 0
                  then 'half yearly'
                  when liq_months =  0 and liqn_days = 0 and liqn_yearsand > 0
                  then ' yearly' 
                  else 'other'
             end)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aswell user union all

```
WITH da(Other_columns,liqn_years, liq_months, liqn_days) AS ( 
SELECT 'Other_colums', 0,0,1 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'Other_colums',12,0,0 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'Other_colums',0,3,0 FROM dual
)
SELECT Other_columns, 'Yearly' AS output  FROM da WHERE liqn_years > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Other_columns, 'Monthly' AS output  FROM da WHERE liqn_years > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Other_columns, 'quaterly' AS output  FROM da WHERE liqn_years > 0
```

Result

> ```
> OTHER_COLUMNS|OUTPUT  |
> -------------|--------|
> Other_colums |Yearly  |
> Other_colums |Monthly |
> Other_colums |quaterly|
> ```